# Repeat string keys of dict based on integer value and form a single string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary

Is it possible to save several prints from a for-loop as string variable?

E.g. I have a dictionary and that has letters as keys, and each key's value represents how often the key should be printed. The overall printout should just be a string, that is then saved as variable. Simplified example:

```
hand = {'a':1, 'q':1, 'l':3, 'm':1, 'u':1, 'i':1}
for letter in hand.keys():
    for j in range(hand[letter]):
        print(letter, end="") #should print out e.g. uilllqma
```

I am aware that I can just append items to an (empty) list with each iteration of the for-loop, however, was wondering if I can do it directly from the printout (without adding to a list first and then printing the list as string).

```
a = ... #assign e.g. uilllqma to a
print(a) #prints 'uillqma'
```

Comment: Where does the value `'uillqma'` come from so it could be assigned to variable `a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplication of a string with a integer value say `n` repeats the value of original string by `n` times. For example:

```
>>> hand = {'a':1, 'q':1, 'l':3, 'm':1, 'u':1, 'i':1}
>>> for k, v in hand.items():
...     print(k * v)
...
a
i
m
lll
q
u
```

So, in order to get all the results as a single string, you may join the *generator* expression as:

```
>>> ''.join(k*v for k, v in hand.items())
'aimlllqu'
```

Comment: very smooth! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You do know the order isn't guaranteed with a `dict` they are unordered.

But you can do a `join()` with a generator expression:

```
>>> print(''.join(k for k, v in hand.items() for _ in range(v)))
lllmaiuq
```

Comment: yes, aware of that, but in this case doesn't matter. thanks for your solution, works well

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simple concatenate letters:

```
hand = {'a':1, 'q':1, 'l':3, 'm':1, 'u':1, 'i':1}
new_str = ""
for letter in hand.keys():
    for j in range(hand[letter]):
        new_str += letter
```

but use .join() instead is more concise.